# How can I encode " ' "

Tags: java, encoding

I'm working on Java with URL and I don't know how to encode the " ' " character.

I don't want to use URLEncoder since it replaces spaces with + and I need %20

```
private String encoder(String param) {
    return param.replaceAll("\\s", "%20").replaceAll("\\'", "%27");
}
```

This is the code i'm trying but it doesn't work, do you have any ideas on how to replace this " ' " ? Or know another method better than it?

Thank you!!

Comment: I am doing this
       private String encoder(String param) {
        return param.replaceAll("\\s", "%20").replaceAll("\\'","%27" );//.replaceAll();
    }

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode(url).replaceAll("\\+", "%20");`?

Comment: Well, if the only problem you're having with URLEncoder is that spaces are replaced by `+` you could replace that afterwards, i.e. first encode using URLEncoder and then replace `+` with `%20`.

Comment: Why do you need %20? + for space is valid URL encoding

Comment: Note for future questions: "it doesn't work" doesn't help us answer the question. You should always explain in what ways it doesn't work, e.g. what you expect (you stated that) and what you get instead (ideally some examples). Also please read [ask] for some more information on good questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answers : the problem is that URLEncoder changes the / into %2F so I can't use it.
And it doesn't work with my method because It does not change the ' into %27.
Is it more clear?

Comment: No, why do you claim it's about the + but now suddenly it's about the /? Please put all information in your question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `'` symbol, just enclose it in double quotes

`param.replaceAll("\\s", "%20").replaceAll("'", "%27");`

Another way is to use `java.net.URLEncoder` class to encode URL and replace `+` symbols to `%20`

`java.net.URLEncoder.encode("URL with spaces'", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20")`